# Member most ancient

Tags: riddle, word, word-property

I'm in a devilish one,
I'm in heaven's son;
I'm in landowners' class,
I'm in rule not by lass;
I'm in wealth on top,
I'm in compound from crop;
I'm in a seeker's tool,
I'm in a ruler cruel

What am I?

Comment: The [tag:word] tag means the answer is a word, right? (Not e.g. a letter.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes, the answer is a single word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The words:

> `I'm in a devilish one,` -> ARCHFIEND
>  `I'm in heaven's son;` -> STARCHILD (told by OP in chat; I had ARCHANGEL originally)
>  `I'm in landowners' class,` -> SQUIREARCHY
>  `I'm in rule not by lass;` -> PATRIARCHY
>  `I'm in wealth on top,` -> OLIGARCHY?
>  `I'm in a gum drop;` -> STARCH
>  `I'm in a seeker's tool,` -> SEARCHLIGHT
>  `I'm in a ruler cruel` -> AUTARCH

leading to the answer

> ARCH.

Title:

> each word connects to the answer. An ARCH-something might be the **most**; an ARCHAEO-something might be **ancient**; and an ARCH is a member? (Again, OP helped in chat with this.)

Comment: Unfortunately, the one you're most sure about is not correct - the next most, however, is